# What is the difference between different controllers provided in ros_control?

Tags: ros, ros-control, ros-kinetic, ros-controllers, gazebo-ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As mentioned in the official [documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_control), the list of available controllers are:

- effort_controllers
- joint_effort_controller
- joint_position_controller
- joint_velocity_controller
- joint_state_controller

  - joint_state_controller
- position_controllers

  - joint_position_controller
- velocity_controllers

  - joint_velocity_controller

I want to know the difference between `effort_controllers/joint_position_controller` and `position_controllers/joint_position_controller` and how to use a position controller and which of the above to use?

My application is a joint velocity control of a two link manipulator in Gazebo using ROS Control.

I'm using ROS Kinetic with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Gazebo version is 7.12

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/292248/what-is-the-difference-between-different-controllers-provided-in-ros_control?/) by [aniket0112](https://answers.ros.org/users/33856/aniket0112/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-05-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see if the accepted answer to #q203404 clears this up.

Summarising: as an example`effort_controllers` assume the hw they are controlling supports *effort* input (ie: force, torque) and so produce efforts to implement a specific control law.

Concretely: think of a torque-controlled joint and the desire to run a position control loop over it. You'd have to use torques to do that.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4